# loading python after the application is up and running

Tags: python-2.7, runtime

What is the best way to load a python module/file after the whole python program is up and running. My current idea is to save the new python file to disk and call import on it. I am working with python 2.7.

Each new python file will have pre-known functions, that will be called by the already running application.

Comment: When OTHER than runtime would you load a module?  What is it about your situation that would  prevent the standard use of import from working?

Comment: I meant the whole program has been loaded and is up and running. While runtime I want to add another python file, that will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The import statement is like any other executable statement, and can be executed at any point during execution.